# How evil was Uncle Six before he acquired the Wu piece?

Tags: wu-assassins

It's pretty clear that, at the start of the  series, Uncle Six is pretty evil. Besides the minor fact of being a crime lord, he also has a habit of incinerating his own lackeys, rounding up random chefs to be interrogated or killed, and so forth. However, was he always this way?

The first Wu assassin certainly seems to think that it's intrinsically bad to have a Wu piece; similarly, Uncle Six refers to seeing the fire behind his eyes in a fashion that implies that it exerts a negative influence on him. Not to mention that Uncle Six himself wants it out of him, and that they perform an exorcism of sorts to remove it, during which he says things in a demonic voice. On the other hand, Kai says that it is what people do with the Wu pieces that is evil, not the pieces themselves, perhaps suggesting that it is people's own flaws that tempt them to evil.

So, what made Uncle Six so evil? The Wu piece, or his own demons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was likely a combination of both. In the flashback clips we see throughout the show, he was a gangster before he gained the Wu piece, and was doing "evil" gangster-y things. But gaining the Wu piece allowed him to take his evil to a whole new level, such as incinerating lackeys because he was in a bad mood. Without the Wu piece, Uncle Six would likely have been a typical gangster, trying to act like he was The Godfather. He might not even have made it to being the gangster boss.

Without knowing about the Wu pieces or being involved with them, there would be no reason for him to

> join forces with the good guys and fight against other people who had a Wu piece. He never would have become a hero character.